# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ClassManager' of undefined

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, core-ui, extreact

I'm getting an error, while integrating React CoreUI Bootstrap project with **ExtReact**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ClassManager' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (ExtJSComponent.js:97)
```

And that `Object.anonymous` line is in the file:

*node_modules\@extjs\reactor\src\ExtJSComponent.js* and looks like this:

```
    const Ext = window.Ext;

    var CLASS_CACHE = {
            Grid: Ext.ClassManager.getByAlias('widget.grid'),
            ...
```

And that's ALL I get.

Can someone please give me at least some directions if not the whole answer.

Comment: is ExtJSComponent file made by you ?

Comment: @Tejas I get the same exception from this file so it isn't custom. See stack trace from OP.

Comment: In [ExtReact](http://docs.sencha.com/extreact/6.5.0/modern/Ext.ClassManager.html) doc there is no method `Ext.ClassManager.getByAlias()`